# C++: Segmentation Fault (11) error when trying to read a file and pass it into a 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, fstream

So I'm extremely new to C++ and I'm trying to read in a file from the command line and then move it into a 2D char array, but I keep getting this error whenever I run the program: "Terminated due to signal: SEGMENTATION FAULT (11)". Does anyone know why? And if anyone has any code suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_ROW = 24;
const int MAX_COL = 80;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    string line;
    char textArray[MAX_ROW][MAX_COL];

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(argv[0]);
    getline(inFile, line);
    while(line.length() > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
            textArray[row][i] = line[i];
        row++;
        if(line.length() > col)
            col = line.length();
        getline(inFile, line);
    }
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debug THEN post to SO once you have a better idea what is happening. Start with `inFile.open(argv[0]);` - no error checking and are you sure that is the file you want to open?

Comment: I don't see any range-testing that would prevent you from overflowing your array bounds.

Answer (score 0):

It can occur such a way that the condition in the while loop

```
while(line.length() > 0)
```

will be always equal to true and you will get an infinite loop.

Actually this condition

```
while(line.length() > 0)
```

does not check whether the previous call of getline was successful.

Rewrite the loop the following way

```
#include <cstring>

//...

while ( row < MAX_ROW && getline(inFile, line) )
{
    std::strncpy( textArray[row], line.c_str(), MAX_COL );
    textArray[row][MAX_COL - 1] = '\0'; 
    row++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably because of an index out of bounds. Check if the line length exceeds the array-size.

try `gdb YOURAPPLICATION` to debug which line gives that error (make sure you used the -g flag when compiling your binary).